# How can I make swiping between activities happen (android)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, swipe

I've searched around the internet for my problem, but I didn't find a good answer for my problem.

**What I want:** I want to implement a swipe from right to left which then lets me go from my MainActivity to my TimeSetActivity.

**What is my problem?:** I have tried to code this idea, but the AVD doesn't go to the TimeSetActivity after swiping from right to left. Not even when I change the swipe values around. It's as if I don't initialize the gesture. (there is no error occuring in the code itself)

My code:

```
package com.example.wirelessthermostat;



    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void nextIntent(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimesetActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
     try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH){
                return false;
            }
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimesetActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } 
            // left to right swipe
            else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimesetActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Just to be sure, did you try it out on a real device and not just the AVD ?

Comment: Add some Log.d calls to be sure that the expected onEvent methods are being called.

Comment: For the past couple of years, the standard approach for this would be to use fragments, particularly in conjunction with a `ViewPager`, instead of activities.

Comment: I didn't try it out on a real device, for some reason it doesn't show up on eclipse. though I think that shouldn't be a problem? CommonsWare, can you send me a link to a tutorial which you think could be meaningful to me? Thank you